# Authenticating Google Cloud Speech via GRPC on C# using an API key

Tags: c#, interceptor, google-speech-api

i want to implement streaming voice recognition on C# on GRPC, but only have an API KEY

this type of key --> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

i know by searching the web that in others languages (android, IOs) they can "intercept" and add a header with the key like:

Metadata.Key.of("x-goog-api-key", "value");

how can i make the same BUT in c#?

my code, if it is neccesary for any reason.

```
public static async Task<object> StreamingRecognizeAsync(Stream audio)
    {
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();

        var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();


        // Write the initial request with the config.
        await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
            new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
            {
                StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                    {
                        Encoding =
                        RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                        SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                        LanguageCode = "en",
                    },
                    InterimResults = true,
                }
            });
        // Print responses as they arrive.
        Task printResponses = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
                default(CancellationToken)))
            {
                foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream
                    .Current.Results)
                {
                    foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = await audio.ReadAsync(
                buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                {
                    AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                    .CopyFrom(buffer, 0, bytesRead),
                });
            await Task.Delay(500);
        };

        await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
        await printResponses;
        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

gRPC allows passing additional settings per-call.
In your case, the following should do the trick:

```
speech.StreamingRecognize(Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.CallSettings.FromHeader("x-goog-api-key", YOUR_API_KEY));
```

(Note: are you sure it's *x-goog-api-key* and not simply *x-api-key*?)